# Should I always use FormData in react?

Tags: reactjs, forms, api, security

I´m building an application where I´ve got a login form and when I send the user data to the API I use the object of useState instead of a FormData object, Is it correct? Is there any difference between using FormData or not? Is it insecure?
This is my code:

````
 const [datos, setDatos] = useState({
    nombre: '',
    apellidos: '',
    email: '',
    password: ''
  })

const handleSubmit = async (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
   await axios({
  
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/register',
      method: 'POST',
      data: datos,
    }).then(response => console.log(response)); 
    console.log(datos)
  } ```
````

Answer (score 1):

No it's not a compulsion. Generally, to send multipart form data like images or some sort of files with Axios, you need to use the `FormData` class.

Nonetheless, if you are just sending data containing strings, numbers, or objects (as you are), then sending them in the `json/object` format is sufficient.

For example,

```js
// body {firstName: 'Fred', lastName: 'Flintstone'} 

axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

And yes security is handled by Axios only. Axios Is More Secure, Featuring Built In Cross Site Forgery (XSRF) Protection.